# probability of selecting a ball from n balls each having any number from 1 to 365

Tags: probability

let n balls each bearing any number between 1 to 365 are placed in a row and a ball is selected at random. Let "P" be the probability that the number on selected ball is same as the number of any one ball placed on the left of it and all balls to left of it bear distinct numbers. If for "P" to be maximum, the position of selected ball counting from left to right is K. find the value of K?

can someone help me out with this question, as for the source I dont from where exactly is it from, I just stumbled upon it while going through a test paper, that gave in my high school.

I have thought that for the maximum probability to occur the sample space or total possible out comes must be large by putting K value 1 we seem to be getting it but with the given answer i can say K=1 isn't allowed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem what you know about probabilities, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: $K = 1$ is clearly not permitted.  Can you compute $P_K = $ the value of $P$ for a specific **fixed** value of $K$, for each $K \in \{2,3,4\}$?  In accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) I advise editing your question to show work, re at least **attempting** to compute  $P_K$, for each $K \in \{2,3,4\}.$

Comment: Looking at the balls from left to right, which ball is most likely to be the first ball to have a number that has already appeared?

Comment: Are the numbers randomly assigned to the balls? This seems like a poorly worded question. I may be missing something.

Comment: The number $n$ seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming the numbers on the balls are assigned uniformly and randomly from $1$ To $365.$ Anything else gets *much* harder.)

The probability is: $$p_K=\frac{K-1}{365}\prod_{k=0}^{K-2}\left(1-\frac{k}{365}\right)$$
The product is the probability that the first $K-1$ are all different, and $\frac{K-1}{365}$ is the probability of the $K$th  ball matching one of the previous balls.

Then $$D_K=\frac{P_{K+1}}{P_K}=\dfrac{\frac K{365}\cdot\left(1-\frac{K-1}{365}\right)}{\frac{K-1}{365}}=\dfrac{K(366-K)}{365(K-1)}$$

Now $D_K>1$ is equivalent to:

$$365(K-1)<K(366-K)$$

Or:

$$K^2-K-365<0.$$

So this means $P_K$ is increasing until $K^2-K-365\geq 0,$ after which, $P_K$ is decreasing.

The positive root of $x^2-x-365$ is:

$$x_0=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\cdot 365}}2.$$
and $p_K$ is maximized when $$K=\lceil x_0\rceil=20$$

---

I suppose if $n<20,$ then the maximum is at $K=n.$ Otherwise, $n$ is irrelevant.

---

The heart of the answer is to conjecture  $p_K$ is increasing initially, and then decreasing.  The above shows this to be true, so we only need to find the first $K$ where $P_{K+1}<P_{K}.$

You could use the difference $P_{k+1}-P_{k},$ rather than the quotient, I suppose, but they amount to the same, and the immediate cancelling made the quotient seem attractive.

Technically, since $P_1=0,$ it would have been better to invert the quotient. Doesn’t really affect the math much.

---

If, instead of $365,$ the balls had numbers from $1$ to $6,$ then $x_0=3.$

The probabilities are:

$$\begin{align}P_1&=0\\
P_2&=\frac16\\
P_3&=\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{18}\\
P_4&=\frac3{6}\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac46=\frac{5}{18}\\
P_5&=\frac{4}{6} \cdot\frac56\cdot\frac46\cdot \frac36=\frac5{27}\\
P_6&= \frac{5}{6} \cdot\frac56\cdot\frac46\cdot \frac36\cdot\frac26=\frac{25}{324}\\
P_7&= \frac56\cdot\frac46\cdot \frac36\cdot\frac26\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac5{324}
\end{align}$$

Here, $P_3=P_4$ share the maximum, because $x_0$ is exactly an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed poorly worded.

My take on the problem: each ball is assigned a number from 1 to 365 with equal probability.  The numbers on all the balls are jointly independent.

For $k = 2, 3, ..., 366$, let $p_k$ be the probability that A) ball 1 thru $k-1$ have $k-1$ distinct colors, and B) one of them matches the color of ball $k$.  (Obviously, $p_k = 0$ for $k \ge 367$ from pigeon-hole.)

Without loss of generality, let the ball $k$ color be "red". Then a qualified event is that the first $k-1$ has "red" and $k-2$ other colors.

The number of qualified events = $(k-1)! C(364, k-2)$. The total number of events = $365^{k-1}$. Therefore $p_k = \frac{(k-1) 364!}{(366-k)!365^{k-1}}$.

Sanity check: $p_2 = \frac{1}{365}$ and $p_{366} = \frac{365!}{365^{365}}$.

$k = 2$ maximizes the $p_k$.

Edit: I was too in haste.  The argmax is indeed not $k= 2$.  I will sort this out later.

Comment: No, $k=2$ does not maximize $p_k.$

Comment: Do you agree with me on my general $p_k$ expression?

Comment: I think so. Compute $p_3/p_2.$ it should be $2\cdot 364/365>1.$

Comment: Thomas, I didn't look at your answer.  Do we have the same expression?

Comment: I didn’t simplify mine in terms of factorials, but I think they are equal.

Comment: I checked yours against k = 2 and 366.  They matched.  So they must be the same.  At first glance, I couldn't follow your logic so I re-invented the wheel.  And there is indeed more work to figure out the argmax.  Since you already did it, I won't spend any more time on this.  Good work, Thomas!